# Laravel - validation date specific date

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

Can i set a specific date for my validation?

```
'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today',
```

for example something like this

```
 'event_start' => 'required|date|after:Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()',
```

This doesn't work of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
'event_start' => 'required|date|after:'.Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(),
```

Don't forget to put this after namespace:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: yeah that's it..i didn't know you can concatenate on rules